# zend search engine, need some guidance in the right direction please

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, zend-framework

I have been looking at manuals of the Zend search engine, but I don't really understand much of it. I have a php website (classifieds) and I want users to be able to search my mysql database for records.

Can someone explain a little more about the Zend search engine, and how I should actually 'install' it.

I don't have my own server (hosting company) so I would appreciate all the help I can get.

I have tried searching for tutorials of this without any luck...

Basically, I need a good guide on how to install it and implement it to the website... Zends own guide seemed a little hazy with words they have made up relative to their own products, and not words I really understood... or maybe I'm way off :)

If you need any more input, please let me know and I will update this Q...

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about Zend_Search_Lucene? If so, why not tag it zend-framework and lucene then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the problem is in [finding tutorials](http://www.google.de/search?q=using+zend_search_lucene), but check out

- http://devzone.zend.com/article/91
- http://ganeshhs.com/zend-framework/zend-search-lucene-part1